# Push live update with XMPP

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am implementing a feature to push real-time updates to clients (web, android, ios). Instead of implementing my own websocket solution, I use OpenFire. I am not sure if this is how people normally push live update, or XMPP server is for messaging only. Please give me feedback on my approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. In all three mentioned platforms you are **not allowed** to maintain socket(or websocket) connection to your server, as typical XMPP connection works. You should forward updates to platform "push service" (APNS, GCM, MPNS) and it will push updates to registered clients.
2. "Push updates" are just notifications about new content available on server, they are not guaranteed to be delivered and not reliable to transfer large amounts of data. Your client still need to connect and fetch new content from server. In this case you can reuse XMPP or any other suitable protocol for exchanging data with your server and clients.
3. If you are familiar with XML and it is not a problem for you to serialize your data in XML-based form - XMPP may be a good choice, otherwise you can choose much simpler data transfer format.

Comment: what do you mean **not allowed**?

Comment: Isn't Push Notification not to be trusted as they are known to be unreliable (not guaranteed to be delivered instantly)?

Comment: Apparently I did read your message to come up with my question. You said Push updates are not "guaranteed to be delivered and not reliable to transfer large amounts of data". So how can I rely on something that is unreliable to prompt the app to fetch update?